# error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘:’ token

Tags: c++

I am trying to run this code by making separate header file. But first of all I am trying to build the header file in Code Blocks. But I get a number of these errors. Is there some syntax error or some other error?

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/116345/skip-list-implementation?newreg=0efcfbee15fc49ec967da28a0952abd6

Error:
/DPDP/Skip_List/main.c|3|error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘:’ token

Comment: Please include your relevant source code into the question. The code you linked is C++, not C. Please use proper language tags.

Comment: This error isn't in the header file, it's in `main.c`. The file you linked looks looks okay, so the error is likely in your version. Posting that version would help identify the error.

Comment: You have C++ code in main.c file. Which compiler do you use and how do you invoke it to compile your files?

Comment: Never include code as pictures (accessibility problems) or on an external site (the site may go down), instead copy the code into the question and format it as a code block. Questions doing the above are off-topic.

Comment: @tambre . Sure will keep in mind from next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to compile C++ code as C. C and C++ are different languages, and your C compiler is complaining about C++-specific syntax.

Try compiling the code as C++. For most compilers it should be sufficient to rename your file `main.cpp`.

Comment: Brutal mistake. Thanks